# Jersey Client : mapping between collection xml and list java objects

Tags: java, xml, jersey-client

I am stuck mapping a collection of xml elements to a list of java objects. There should be some different content value, but the output is showing `0` for each element.

**Update** : I tested same code with mine custom web services. It works fine.

Here is mine updated xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<users>
 <user>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>James</name>
    <profession>teacher</profession>
 </user>
 <user>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Kelly</name>
    <profession>teacher</profession>
 </user>
</users>`
```

Here is the earlier xml code:

```
//XML

<CUSTOMERList xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<CUSTOMER xlink:href="http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/0/">0</CUSTOMER>
<CUSTOMER xlink:href="http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/1/">1</CUSTOMER>
<CUSTOMER xlink:href="http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/6/">6</CUSTOMER>
:
:
```

And here is the `CustomerList` class:

```
//Customerlist POJO

@XmlRootElement(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerList {
   private int CUSTOMER;

   public int getCUSTOMER() {
     return CUSTOMER;
   }

   public void setCUSTOMER(int cUSTOMER) {
     CUSTOMER = cUSTOMER;
   }

}


// Jersey Client

Client client = Client.create();
URI uri = new URI("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/");
WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri);

List<CustomerList> customers = webResource.path("").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(new GenericType<List<CustomerList>>(){});

for(CustomerList c : customers){
    System.out.println("### " + c.getCUSTOMER() );
}
```

[This is the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMGqd.png)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You should have some sort of collection in Customerlist, otherwise it keeps overwriting the assigned values. Then, the root element should be Customerlist and its element should be an xmlelement (the collection et.al.) named customer

Comment: @Tony Brix      thanks for your comment. Yes I already did make a 'customer' collection in Customerlist class. But man result remains same.